# Is there a general term for $A\oplus B = \{a \oplus b | a\in A, b\in B\} $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology

Is there a general term that specifies that if an operator $\oplus$ is applied to two sets, it's actually applied to all possible pairs of elements of the two sets?

Or is that always the case and goes without saying?

Matrix addition for example is also an elemtent-wise operation, but it does not apply the operator to every possible combination of elements, but only some. How would that *way-of-applying-an-operator-to-things-that-have-more-things-in-them* be called?

Comment: It is usually specified in the definition of the operator that that is exactly what it means.

Comment: Note that matrices aren't really sets, per se

Comment: @Omnomnomnom sorry, I'm lacking the terminology to express *"something that an operator can be applied to" that's also "something that has more (possibly different) somethings in it that the operator can also be applied to"* in a mathematical term. If I have **Peanut butter** and **space shuttle** and apply the operator **smear onto** to them, how would you call the way that operator was applied if every astronaut ends up being covered in peanut butter? I hope this description of the problem is closer to home for you (user name suggests that). =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For subsets $A,B$ of some additively written ambient group $(G,+)$ (or also just semigroup) the set $A + B = \{a + b \colon a \in A, \, b \in B \}$ is often called the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition). This name is especially common in a geometric context.

But the concept is very important in Additive Combinatorics and Additive Number Theory. There it is so ubiquitous that it is often simply called sum of the sets $A$ and $B$, or sum-set of $A$ and $B$. And in this context it basically goes without saying that this is meant. Though there are still subtle points for example for summing $A$ with itself one sometimes wants to exclude $a+a$, and denotes this then as $A \hat{+} A $ or $2\widehat{\phantom{o}}A$ so that some brief indication what exactly is meant can still be desirable.

Given your example of matrices, let me mention that given functions $f$ and $g$ the operation of constructing the function $x \mapsto f(x) +g(x)$ is often called  the pointwise sum of $f$ and $g$. And the same for  product.  Recall that a sequence is also a function, and also a matrix or a vector can be thought of as a function (defined on the set of indexes), so this applies to them. In that context then termwise or elementwise can also be used rather than pointwise.

Comment: The Minkowski sum inspired the question.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this cannot be used for all operators. Consider $A \cup B$, which is certainly not all possible unions of an element in $A$ with an element in $B$, though in ZFC we certainly have the set $\{ a \cup b : a \in A \land b \in B \}$.